# How to use TortoiseMerge with Visual SourceSafe 2005?

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, merge, diff, visual-sourcesafe

I tried by setting up a custom editor for "File Difference" in Tools->Options->Custom Editors with the command line: "tortoiseproc /command:diff /path:%1 /path2:%2". TortoiseMerge launches but it can't find the files to compare. The files to compare should be in a temp folder but they aren't there. SourceSafe isn't making the files available.

Has anyone succesfully used Tortoise to diff and merge files in SourceSafe?

A theory I have for my problem: SourceSafe incorrectly detects that Tortoise has exited and finished its operations just after it called the command for Tortoise to start and immediately deletes the temp files it just created (if they ever got created). Even though I have this theory, I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
TortoiseMerge.exe %1 %2
```

instead. TortoiseProc only works on svn working copies.

Comment: Working!

Could you help me out with the command line to use for "file merge" too? The possible entries I get when calling "tortoisemerge.exe /?" don't match the parameters described by visual sourcesafe exactly.

Comment: I don't know the parameters that sourcesafe uses. Just pass the one you have and leave the ones you don't get from sourcesafe.